# MySQL Composite Primary Key Duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table with a composite Primary Key.

```
CREATE TABLE `courses` (
 `termNum` varchar(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Term Number',
 `classNum` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 `subject` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `courseNum` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `classTitle` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `numUnits` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `dates` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `startTime` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `endTime` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `generalStudies` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
 `instructor` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Staff',
 `seatsOpen` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `dayList` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `miss` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`classNum`,`termNum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Originally I was going to just use `classNum` as the Primary Key, but it turns out that across terms it may actually repeat. To avoid problems, I was hoping to combine both the `classNum` and the `termNum` together into the Primary Key. Originally my queries to add data were like this:

```
INSERT INTO `courses` (`termNum`,`classNum`,`courseNum`,`subject`,`generalStudies`,`classTitle`,`numUnits`,`dates`,`dayList`,`startTime`,`endTime`,`location`,`instructor`,`seatsOpen`,`miss`)
VALUES ('2136','74581','101','ACC','','Accounting','3','10/21 - 12/13(C)','M W Th','6:00 PM','10:00 PM',' TBA','The Professor','50','0')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE `courseNum` = '101',`subject` = 'ACC',`generalStudies` = '',`classTitle` = 'Accounting',`numUnits` = '3',`dates` = '10/21 - 12/13(C)',`dayList` = 'M W Th',`startTime` = '6:00 PM',`endTime` = '10:00 PM',`location` = 'TBA',`instructor` = 'The Professor',`seatsOpen` = '50',`miss` = '0';
```

However, after a handful of runs I noticed that it was only ever updating the same row. So I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO `courses` (`termNum`,`classNum`,`courseNum`,`subject`,`generalStudies`,`classTitle`,`numUnits`,`dates`,`dayList`,`startTime`,`endTime`,`location`,`instructor`,`seatsOpen`,`miss`)
VALUES ('2137','74580','101','ACC','','Accounting','3','10/21 - 12/13(C)','M W Th','6:00 PM','10:00 PM','Tempe - TBA','The Professor','50','0');
INSERT INTO `courses` (`termNum`,`classNum`,`courseNum`,`subject`,`generalStudies`,`classTitle`,`numUnits`,`dates`,`dayList`,`startTime`,`endTime`,`location`,`instructor`,`seatsOpen`,`miss`)
VALUES ('2137','90000','101','ACC','','Accounting','3','10/21 - 12/13(C)','M W Th','6:00 PM','10:00 PM','Tempe - TBA','The Professor','50','0');
```

And I get:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '32767-2137' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Notice that I changed the `classNum` but not the `termNum`, so clearly it's not using the whole Primary Key. But what really confuses me is if I instead change the `termNum` and leave the `classNum` the same, it works perfectly. I've tried switching the order of the fields in the PRIMARY KEY () line, but it's the same thing.

I've searched around and there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong. I tried rebuilding the tables, but no change there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inserting value of `74581` on `classNum`  but the actual value that will be inserted is `32767`.

The reason is because you are using `smallint(6)` datatype on column `classNum` which has the maximum value of `32767`. Try changing the data type that can hold larger range of number, ex. `INT UNSIGNED`

```
classNum INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

for more information about Numeric Datatype Range, please see the link below

- [Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)
- [other link...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I usually just use INT, but I was trying to keep this database small. When I looked at the documentations, for some reason I had it in my head that the values were in the thousands, not the ten thousands, so I figured smallint was fine.